# live streaming protocols and FFmpeg as streaming protocol or codec?

Tags: web, network-protocols, ip-camera

I have been studying about streaming protocols. but I confused about FFmpeg.
I do not know it is codec or streaming protocol.any one can help me about FFmpeg?

Comment: ffmpeg is library/program that contains decoder encoder and also have streaming protocol. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: thanks for your answer